# How can I justify text?

Tags: notepad++

Before I start, I would like to state that I'm not a programmer at all. I use N++ as a basic word-processor. I know it's not AT ALL its main function, but it's the best software to do that kind of things.

I tried to find an answer, but there is still none. So I ask my question here. How would it be possible to justify text in N++, the same way one can Ctrl+J his text ?

Yes, I know that plain text can not be justified. But I'm looking for a kind of workaround, something visual. For those who know what I'm talking about, I would like to get what I have when I Ctrl+J on softs like FocusWriter : no real justification, but only because it makes typing and reading easier.

Comment: Short answer: It is not possible. Notepad++ is a plain text editor not a word processor.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, [there is no plugin available](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Central) to do anything resembling this functionality.

The closest thing would be the [TextFX plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/) which has a feature to wrap your lines (TextFX->TextFX Edit->ReWrap text). But this is not what you are looking for.

At the moment, Notepad++ only supports displaying text 'as-is'. Meaning, a space, or character, will always have the same width. Also, there is no feature for page formatting. There is no page-width. In order to have a justify-feature, you would need page-width, and flexible width spaces. No features, nor plug-ins exist for this.

The nearest custom hack I can imagine, would be a plugin where you specify your "page-width" in characters, and an algorithm inserts additional white-spaces in between your words to simulate the justify-feature. Of course, this would make actual changes to your text, and not just the way it is being displayed.

Another very popular text-editor, [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/), [does seem to have packages that support this](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Justify). It might be a good idea to have a look at it, because the Notepad++ plugin community is kind of dying a slow death, and [Sublime is on the rise](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=sublime%20text,notepad%2B%2B)... (I haven't made the switch yet either ;) But I do like Sublime a lot too )

To be concrete about my answer to your question:

> How can I justify text [in Notepad++]?

You can't. There's no plugins for it, and it's unlikely that there ever will be. Start working on plan B ;)